# c# Not Updating the Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am using Code First in Asp.net

when I `Update-Database` it said:

> Your startup project DAL doesn't reference
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design. This package is required for the
> Entity Framework Core Tools to work. Ensure your startup project is
> correct, install the package, and try again.

when i install `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design` it said you are using:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error     Could not install package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
> 5.0.9'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2', but the package does not
> contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible
> with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Need Help

Comment: It looks like your package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design 5.0.9' is not compatible with your  '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2'.
Check this out "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard".
 .NET Framework doesn't support .NET Standard 2.1. 
You can try to use some other similar package which is compatible with your .Net framework.

Comment: The error is somewhat self explanatory.

Comment: Try install this `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools package` too.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this Issued The Problem is with my Connection string and I install both EntityFramework6 and EntityFrameworkCore

I use EntityFramework6 and connection string with my Commands solve my issue

EntityFrameWork6\Update-Database -Connection String "Server=sqllocaldb;Initial Catalog=master;Trusted_Connection=false;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"  -Force -ConnectionProviderName "system.data.sqlclient"